# How to view content of a ubuntu installation by starting a live test session?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, permissions, data-recovery

I had **Ubuntu** and also **Windows** installed on my laptop. My laptop burned out(motherboard) but HDD is safe. So I need to take all the files and folders of my Linux OS. My whole development process.

So I connected my HDD to another laptop and booted it via a Ubuntu Live CD.

I can see the files and folders and also home folder. But when I click the home folder I get following error.

> The location could not be displayed. You don't have the **permissions** necessary to view the contents of Chanaka.

Chanaka is my name :)

So how can I get my content back ?

This is not my laptop.

So I also can't use `su` command too. No ?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo` with terminal window command lines? For example this command line (modified), `sudo ls -l /path-to-the-home-directory`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `sudo` / `su` from the LiveCD without problems *(even without password)*, it's a common way of quickly recovering info or doing some maintenance.

You can simply do `sudo cp -a /home/Chanaka /destination/path/of/your/backup/`.

Also keep in mind that if your backup media is formated on *ext4 (also ext2/3 or any *nix filesystem)*, to access your backed up files from your new installation *(or other pc)* you'll have to change their ownership (from *ubuntu* to *myuser*) with `sudo chown -R myuser:myuser /destination/path/of/your/backup/`. This has no sense if backup media is formated on FAT or NTFS filesystems, which doesn't handle/hold unix permissions.

Another option would be directly from LiveCD, **change original files** ownership *(`sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /path`)* or permissions *(`sudo chmod -r 777 /path`)*, and then copy those files from LiveCD file explorer *(Nautilus)*. Note that after that process, **old files have changed** *(ownership or permissions)* and new files will have `ubuntu` user as owner, which is the default LiveCD user (you'll have to `chown` / `chmod` them from the new system).

Only if data is encrypted, would be the only way you´ll can't access the files.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can use su /sudo and add new permission. I can use chmod to make new permissions. no ? Then can I right click on that folder and just copy and paste it to my flash drive ? I don't need current permission. Just only need my projects.

Comment: Yes, you can also change permision with `sudo chmod -r 777 /path` and copy from Files (Nautilus). Keep in mind those copied files will have `ubuntu` user as owner _(default livecd user)_ and old files are _changed_. Answer updated.

Comment: @RootSL Please check if this answer solved your question, then plase report your success or additional issues you have faced. Thanks!